# Using Draw.io diagram in Intranet Confluence

Tags: confluence, intranet, draw.io

I am using Confluence in an Intranet environment, which have no Internet access at all, and want to check whether it is possible to use Draw.io diagram in such environment.

I tried to check from Atlassian and Draw.io websites, but could not find any related information. Could anyone help to advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is how draw.io for Confluence Server is designed to operate.
​
Best Regards,
​